# How to measure microwave frequency with Lecher lines

Tags: rf, high-frequency, microwave, frequency-measurement

I am working on a project where I need to **measure the frequency of some microwaves** (up to 10GHz) and as measurement tool I chose Lecher lines as they are easy and fast to build.

However after building the Lecher lines I found out that it's not recording any frequency, either microwaves or UHF.

The Lecher lines are **~ 40 cm long** and are made of **2mm diameter copper wires** mounted on a wood board. They are held in air by **3 pieces of plastic and spaced by a thin foam**. The lines never touch each other as I used a thin foam as separators between the lines.

As a meter I use a **0-100 uA analog meter**. When performing the measurement, I touch the wires from the meter to the lines from Lecher lines in a parallel way but no change on the meter is recorded. I **also tried to use a red LED as a meter** but it also did not record anything.

As a microwave power source I use the **Wifi router's antenna**.

Can someone **help me debug my setup** so that I would measure microwaves with Lecher lines or if you know other way of measuring the frequency (which is cheap to build), I am open to trying it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The router is modulated using OFDM pulses so it's not the same as a clean sine wave. Not sure if that's the only problem though.

Comment: You need to rectify the signal from the line to be able to measure it with a DC meter. It also may not be sensitive enough to detect the signal.

Comment: @KevinWhite I see. How can I rectify the signal so that the DC meter would pick it up? Is this something like in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOlfuYpT_80 There seems to be some resistors soldered on his meter and he only touches one of his meter's connector to the line. But in my case, I was not using any resistors and was touching both meter's connectors to the two Lecher lines.

Answer (score 1):

To make that meter work you need to translate the microwave frequencies to DC.  I'm suggesting below that you do this with a diode.

I can't guarantee this circuit will work.  If it does, it's because you've made it out of the right components, and kept it as small as possible -- meaning, everything is surface mount components, probably 0603 or smaller, and tight tight.

The theory is that D1 rectifies the RF at the base of the loop into DC, which the meter can pick up.  C1 keeps the DC circuit from being shorted out by the antenna loop and the Lechter wires' shorting bar.  L1 and L2 keep the DC circuit from interfering with the RF circuit (if there's anything you could just remove from this circuit, those would be it -- I think you could make it work with just C1 and D1).

**Absolutely every component you use here needs to be good out to the microwave frequencies common with WiFi**.  You can't just use the hobbyist parts available from surplus stores -- those basically went obsolete in the 1980's.  Giant blobs of through-hole components just won't work here -- basically, the parts need to be small in comparison to a wavelength, or they'll start looking like other things to the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0wnlG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks TIm! What values would you suggest for the D1 and C1?

Comment: Choose C1 so that it has a capacitive reactance less than 50 ohms at the lowest frequency you're interested in.  I can't help with D1 -- go shopping, and find an RF diode that seems to work in that range.  It'll probably be a Schottkey, and hopefully not too challenging to get.

Comment: Just added a PMLL4448 high frequency diode (https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMLL4148L_PMLL4448.pdf)  and a 100pF capacitor and it still did not work. Now sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't think that this will work with an analogue meter of the type you have shown. Have you checked that this meter isn't a moving coil meter (one only suitable for DC measurements) or, if indeed it is a moving iron meter, then what sort of frequency response does it have. I doubt that a moving iron meter of the type shown will respond adequately to 10 kHz let alone 10 GHz.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andy! This indeed it suitable only for DC measurements. Have not thought of this. Here is a link to the actual product: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Analog-Panel-Current-Meter-0-100uA-DC-Ammeter-M4247-Military-USSR/193344607229

So if the meter is the issue with my Lecher lines, what other ways I can measure the frequency? I tried to use a small red LED but it was also not working. But for my multimeter, the minimum ACV is 200.

Comment: Use a frequency meter. Use a spectrum analyser.

Comment: Oh, I don't have a spectrum analyzer. I was looking some cheaper ways to do this. The whole point of this project  is to measure the frequency with Lecher lines. I could buy a frequency meter but that defies the main goal of the project.